# NavigationService - GoBack or Navigate

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigationservice

This is maybe more of a design issue, but has also a technical background.

In my current app I have following views:

MovieOverview
FriendsOverview

The app starts and will show 'my' movie collection ( with the MovieOverview view ) and you'll have a possibility to navigate to 'my friends' through an appbar button.

When on the FriendsOverview view, I'll see 'my' friends and when you press/select a friend, I do a NavigationService.GoBack to the MovieOverview view, BUT with a parameter stating the new selected username ( the selected friend ). This will refresh the MovieOverview view and it will show the 'friend' movie collection.

When at this point you press the friends appbar button, I will show 'my' friends again, so the original unchanged lists ( and not the friends of the 'selected friend' ).

Drawback on this approach, when you selected a friend an get back on the MovieOverview view, pressing the hard BACK button will exit the app, because of the NavigationService.GoBack I coded from the FriendsOverview view to the MovieOverview view.

So my question, how do you design/technical o about this?
Any tips, suggestions, everything is welcome. I need to brainstorm on this...

Comment: I solved this by splitting the Movie page in 2, one general ( so I can add more User related stuff ) and one for Friends collections...

Answer (score 0):

I think, when you click on a friend on friends page you don't need to call GoBack. Instead, call NavigateTo with a parameter of friend. On the Movie page, add header. User must understand whom movies are shown now. When it press Back from this page, application go to a previous page in stack, i.e. to friends page. Friends button in app bar must also do the same in friend movies mode (GoBack). If user watch him movies, app bar button must call NavigateTo instead of GoBack.

Comment: Yeah... I tried this, but going from Moviepage back to FriendsPage and then back to 'first' movie page, that page will contain the selected friend and not the current user running the app.